# Split a json array into JS variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON array that is output from an API. The array is similar to this:
`http ://pastebin . com/pHH977Uj`
What is the most delicate way to pick out the various prices in my JavaScript? I'd prefer them to be variables or in an array. I'm fairly new to programming outside of html/PHP for web, so bear with me D:
I've been bugging around this problem for about a week now.

EDIT:
Thanks for the fast responses! What I'm looking for are basically a way to turn every price into a variable similar to coke-usd, pepsi-euro or salty-euro. I don't necessarily need anything else, since I'm only looking to pick out the price of each product in two different currencies. Also, the JSON is as it is, I get it off of an external website, so not much I can do about the structure :/

Comment: What have you tried, what is your actual problem? And how do you want to reduce the structure without loosing information?

Comment: how do you want to adress them ? by price/name/currency/type/... be more specific about what you want exactly

Comment: If this data structure has any semblance to what you really need I believe you will find it severely lacking in short order.  Instead of product/currency/product_variety, you probably want product/product_variety/currency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the link shows a json object, not an array.  Second, you should always handle json with

`var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);`

from there, you can access the properties as usual

`var sodas = obj.soda.usd; // obj, soda, and usd are all objects`

and then you can get each key value pair.

```
 // sodas is an object too, its values are arrays
for (var soda in sodas) {
   console.log (soda, prices.soda[0]);
}
```